# How to find if data is is present in a certain dataframe interval while finding out mean for another column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a timestamp, and I grouped it by 15mins per day to find out the mean emission per month. Here's a sample of dataframe:

```
   plant         CEMS          Timestamp        emission

HINDALCO Ltd.,  CEMS-3      2018-07-01 07:16:30  71
HINDALCO Ltd.,  CEMS-4      2018-07-01 07:20:27  63.75
Mideast         CEMS-1      2018-07-01 07:22:31  491.25
ores_isp        CEMS-1      2018-07-01 07:22:34  367.81
Suraj P.        CEMS-1      2018-07-01 07:22:48  39.56
Jindal          CEMS-26     2018-07-01 07:22:34  1
HINDALCO Ltd.,  CEMS-5      2018-07-01 07:20:27  33.75
```

So now I have to detect that if in an interval of 15mins, there was no data received from 80% of the plants, then it might be an server issue and mean should not be considered in that 15min interval. Help me find that please.

I'm using this code to find 15min interval 'emission' mean.

```
fMin = wn.groupby(['plant_name', 'CEMS', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='15Min')],as_index=False).count()
fMin = fMin[fMin['emission']>0]
fMl = len(fMin)
fMinA =  (fMl * 100) / (96 * dayCount)
```

Comment: So, if the emission data is not received will be marked as `0` or there won't be any entry for that particular plant?

Comment: @yogkm no as it is mentioned in the question, if 80% of the plants do not have any emission in a particular 15 min interval, that 15 interval will not be considered for any plants and for calculation of mean emission

Comment: Please see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration)